# Upload File - Multiform Data

Tags: c#, restsharp

hey how can i replicate this in C# code. I have the file already as byte[] or stream form.

```
$ curl https://someaddress.com/ 
-F parameter1='abc123' \
-F file=@myfile.someextension \
-F parameter2='abc123'
```

**[UPDATE]**

I have tried RestSharp but i got response with status code 0. Actually it doesn't seem to send the request even. {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."}

```
var client = new RestClient("https://someaddress.com");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/",Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

request.AddParameter("parameter1", "abc123");
request.AddParameter("parameter2", "abc123");

request.AddFile("fileData", fileStream.CopyTo, filename);
//request.AddFile("fileData", fileByteArray, filename);

var response= client.Execute(request);
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

This is the stacktrace that i can see inside the response ErrorException field.

```
InnerException = {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at RestSharp.Http.WriteRequestBody(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
at RestSharp.Http.PostPutInternal(String method)
```

Comment: Start by posting what you have tried already

Comment: i have tried RestSharp but it doesnt seem to work. i will update the post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using HttpWebRequest Class or other project but nothing. I have also tried to download and build the project but it didnt work. After some time i found out that the problem was the security protocol. So i have added this line and it worked.

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Answer (score 1):

Experienced same issue (105.2.3), after some research, we decided to get source and track it. However, after building it, problem fixed.

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/860

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either you can use [`HttpWebRequest Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (OR) You can use [RestSharp NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) for same

Comment: i have tried RestSharp but it doesnt seem to work. i will update the post with code

Comment: i have tried using HttpWebRequest class but it stuck in request.GetReqeustStream(). It never executes the requestStream.Write method. 

     Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
     requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
     requestStream.Close();
     return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

i have used the code in here http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c